# Python advance regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text that looks like so:

```
TTL1 | TTL2 | TTL3
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
TTL1 | TTL2 | 
TTL3
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
some text in a line4
some text in a line5
TTL1 | TTL2 | TTL3
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
some text in a line4
...
```

**Explanation**: I have titles rows that sometimes can be seperated to multiple lines, and then I have a lot of other lines.
I want to capture all the titles (even if they are in different lines) and to also capture in one group all the lines that are after the titles.

I am having truoble with the multiline titles and the multiline content and I don't know how to extract it with regex and python.

and ideas please?

Comment: try pandas. http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @harperkoo I know pandas, how can I use it for this? I wanted to get the data with `findall` to put it in a list, and then use pandas. the problem was to get the data.

Comment: I think you want to filter all headers and get the rest data,right? try ```df[(df.TTL1!= "TTL1")```

Comment: @TheDaJon I have updated the answer, look if that solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\s*\n([^\|]*)(?:\n|$)
```

As per op's comment, Strangely the lines can contain | to which makes it difficult to distinguish between title and line therefore the following solution can be tried:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\n(.*?)(?=^\s*\w+\s*\n*\|\s*\n*\w+\s*\n*\|\s*\n*\w+\s*\n*)|^\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\n(.*)$
```

[Updated Regex Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/GX3yCV/3)

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/GX3yCV/2)

Sample Code:

```
import re

regex = r"\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*(\w+)\s*\n([^\|]*)(?:\n|$)"

test_str = ("TTL1 | TTL2 | TTL3\n"
    "some text in a line1\n"
    "some text in a line2\n"
    "some text in a line3\n"
    "TTL1 | TTL2 | \n"
    "TTL3\n"
    "some text in a line1\n"
    "some text in a line2\n"
    "some text in a line3\n"
    "some text in a line4\n"
    "some text in a line5\n"
    "TTL1 | TTL2 | TTL3\n"
    "some text in a line1\n"
    "some text in a line2\n"
    "some text in a line3\n"
    "some text in a line4")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
  print(match.group(1))
  print(match.group(2))
  print(match.group(3))
  print(match.group(4))
```

[Run it here](https://repl.it/ExNk/1)

Sample Output:

```
TTL1
TTL2
TTL3
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
TTL1
TTL2
TTL3
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
some text in a line4
some text in a line5
TTL1
TTL2
TTL3
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
some text in a line4
```

Comment: this is almost what I want, though my line can contains `|` sign, and in the regex we are removing it. how can I include the `|` sign?

Comment: you mean group 4 can contain | sign as well ?

Comment: yes, it also may contain it. it can contain any char.

Comment: If line can contain | .... then how do you distinguish T1|T2|T3  line1 | line2 | line3 why cant line 1 and line 2 and line 3 be title ??? consider these scenario :   t1 | t2 | t3  aa bb cc dd ee ff l1| l2 | l3   pq rsadfa t4| t5| t6 now tell me why l1 l2 and l3 shouldnot be title ?

Comment: this is the file foramt that I have, I have a line of titles that are seperated with `|` (the last title is: `WORD SOME_NUMBERS WORD` and then there is just a content until next title lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach with `re.findall()` function:

```
# lines.txt is a file containing the initial text from your question 
with open('lines.txt', 'r') as fh:
    t = fh.read()
    items = re.findall(r'([A-Z\d\s|]+)([^A-Z]+)', t)

# 'h' contains header, 'lines' contains the lines related to current header 
for h, lines in items:
    print(h.replace('\n', ' '), lines, sep='\n')
```

The output:

```
TTL1 | TTL2 | TTL3 
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3

TTL1 | TTL2 | TTL3 
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
some text in a line4
some text in a line5

TTL1 | TTL2 | TTL3 
some text in a line1
some text in a line2
some text in a line3
some text in a line4
```